# Stitch Fatal Error Occurred - DAY_OF_MONTH

Tags: mysql, stitch

I have a replication set up against MySql. It's been replicating for months. It is set up as Key-Based incremental replication using a timestamp datatype column. Stitch is now reporting the error below. I am not sure what this means or how to resolve.

2023-02-02 10:32:32,987Z tap - FATAL [main] tap-hp-mysql.main - Fatal Error Occurred - DAY_OF_MONTH
2023-02-02 10:32:32,990Z tap - ERROR [main] #error {
2023-02-02 10:32:32,990Z tap - :cause DAY_OF_MONTH
2023-02-02 10:32:32,990Z tap - :via
2023-02-02 10:32:32,990Z tap - [{:type java.sql.SQLException
2023-02-02 10:32:32,990Z tap - :message DAY_OF_MONTH
2023-02-02 10:32:32,990Z tap - :at [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError createSQLException SQLError.java 129]}
2023-02-02 10:32:32,990Z tap - {:type com.mysql.cj.exceptions.WrongArgumentException
2023-02-02 10:32:32,990Z tap - :message DAY_OF_MONTH
2023-02-02 10:32:32,990Z tap - :at [jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl newInstance0 NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java -2]}
2023-02-02 10:32:32,990Z tap - {:type java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
2023-02-02 10:32:32,990Z tap - :message DAY_OF_MONTH
2023-02-02 10:32:32,991Z tap - :at [java.util.GregorianCalendar computeTime GregorianCalendar.java 2645]}]
2023-02-02 10:32:32,991Z tap - :trace

Answer (score 0):

Recently I solved a similarly problem on MariaDB integration with Stitch. I found values from *datetime* columns with invalid range. See on [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) which are the valid *datetime* ranges and search on your database by out-of-range values.